# How can I log SSIS FireWarning events to a SQLProvider?

Tags: logging, ssis

I've currently implemented Logging in a SQL Server Integrated Services (SSIS) 2008 project, by turning off All Logging Events except OnWarning OnTaskFailed and OnError, and can sucessfully log the events to the EventLog. Here is how:

On the ControlFlow tab, right click the background and select `Logging....`,then under `Providers and Logs` table, select `SSIS log profier for Windows event Log` and add a new EventLog provider. 
Click on the `Details` tab, and box-select `OnError`, `OnTaskFailed` and `OnWarning` boxes, then select `Advanced` button and turn off all the heading events except `SourceName`,  and `MessageText`. Click OK, and you have a simple lightweight Events Logger that won't fill your events log with excess log info.

But what would make it even better would be a way to log the pertinent Events directly to a SQL Table so that I can monitor and manage outcomes better. Call it the poor mans MOM service (or SCOM for you following the latest naming convention) if you like.

I've investigate using the `SSIS log provider for SQL Server` but I can't find a way to log this information to a SQL table.

I don't want to write a Custom Logger, just a lightweight and maintainable way of logging these events to my own SQL table.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain the trouble you are having with the native SQL Server log destination? It works fine for me.

I had a package sitting around that would throw warnings and errors called Package2. I enabled SQL Server logging

[image: Logging enabled]

I selected the indicated events
[image: Select specific events]

And only grabbed the desired fields
[image]

I ran the package and it failed wonderfully. I queried the connection I had used to log (catalog SSISDB on a local instance named localsqla in my case)

C:> sqlcmd -S localhost\localsqlA -d SSISDB -W -Q "SELECT L.id, L.source, L.event, L.message FROM dbo.sysssislog L WHERE L.starttime > '2012-01-10'"

And the results. They don't print well here so I delimited it with `|` (space pipe space)

```
id source event message
-- ------ ----- -------
4054 | Package2 | PackageStart | Beginning of package execution.
4055 | Execute SQL Task | OnError | Executing the query "SELECT ? as c1, ? as c2, ? as C3" failed with the following error: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
4056 | Package2 | OnError | Executing the query "SELECT ? as c1, ? as c2, ? as C3" failed with the following error: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
4057 | Execute SQL Task | OnTaskFailed |
4058 | Package2 | OnWarning | SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
4059 | Package2 | PackageEnd | End of package execution.

(6 rows affected)
```

Comment: I don't believe! The syssislog is a System Table, so I couldn't find a reference to the name of the tables was expected a new table to be created in my main list of tables. It was there all the time under Tables > System Tables. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: You can script the table's definition out and drop and recreate if you'd rather have it not in the system table list. SSIS copies it down from msdb if it doesn't already exist in the target catalog.

Comment: Thanks are great, but if you found the answer helpful, you can click the Up arrow to upvote it. If it solved your issue, you may also check the Check Mark to indicate the question has been answered. Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks I can't upvote you yet, but when my reputation score increases I'll come back to you. I've marked your question answered. Hoping I can pass it forward. :-)